# JSoup: Accessing Data Within Multiple HTML classes

Tags: html, jsoup

I recently started using JSoup to do HTML data scraping and I couldn't find enough detailed information on jsoup.org on how to find div classes that are nested within other div classes.

```htm
<div class="Food">
  <a href="/eating/101" class="Eating">
      <div class="Groceries">
        <div class="Vegtables">
        <div class="LeafyGreens"
          <img src="https://RealisticBroccoli.svg" alt="" class="Broccoli-logo"></div>
          <div class="Broccoli Fact">Fun Fact About Broccoli:</div>
          </div></a></div>

    <div class="Food">
      <a href="/eating/102" class="Eating">
      <div class="Groceries">
        <div class="Vegtables">
          <div class="LeafyGreens"
            <img src="https://CartoonBroccoli.svg" alt="" class="Broccoli-logo"></div>
            <div class="Broccoli Fact">Fun Fact About Broccoli:</div>
            </div></a></div>
```

I created a simplistic version of a similar HTML project I am working on. I know it seems like there is an excessive amount of div tags, but its what is making this problem challenging for me. I wanted to scrape the HTML text for the Broccoli Fact that is produced when the A[href] is eating/101 without scraping the fact from eating/102.
From my experience I cannot scrape the "Broccoli Fact" class using one instruction, it doesn't produce any output either. I think that it has something to do with the a href "/eating/101". Thanks for the help!

Comment: you need `<div class="Broccoli Fact">Fun Fact About Broccoli:</div>` this one in jsoup? try this selector `div.Broccoli`

Comment: What is it that you want to scrape exactly? The text within the div with the class="Broccoli Fact"?

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer to your question in oder to mark it as solved. Or, if it is indeed still an open question, try to be more specific and give the community a chance to understand your problem better.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you may have one or both of these 2 problems:

1) In HTML it is possible to assign more than one class name to an element. This is what happens here with `Broccoli Fact`. These are actually two classes: `Broccoli` and `Fact`. In your CSS selector in Jsoup you may want to apply both classes as well. This can be achieved by simply concatenating the classes. Note that a class selector in JSopu CSS does contain the class-name with a preceding dot: `.Broccoli` and `.Fact` So concatenation gives you

```
div.Broccoli.Fact
```

2) In the HTML you give as an example there are more than 1 Broccoli Fact, but you only want to get the first one. There are several ways of dealing with this. Which one is the best is hard to tell without more context knowledge of your task. However, here are some suggestions:

a) gather all Fun Facts of Broccoli but only use the first one. Since Jsoup returns `Elements`, which implements the List interface, you can quite easily access the first element.

b) Use a more precise CSS selector. Something like this could work:

```
div.Food>a[href$=101] div.Broccoli.Fact
```

Have a look here to learn about JSoup CSS selectors: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax